# How i convert String to int?

Tags: java, string, int, numberformatexception, minute

Here's Code, I am trying to convert Minutes which is String type, to integer type but I am having  NumberFormatException error, can anyone help me, how i handle this situation. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Date;

class DateDemo 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        // Instantiate a Date object
        Date date = new Date();

        // display time and date
        String str = String.format("Current Minutes : %tM", date );
        try
        {
            int a = Integer.valueOf(str);
            System.out.print(a);

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error is : "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What number do you expect to get from `"Current Date/Time"`? what is the expected result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/3579095

Comment: What is the value of the String str at the moment you try to parse it?

Comment: i am having this Error : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Current Date/Time : 43" , actually i want program to convert that "43" which is String , to integer type.

Comment: @PatrickNijhuis 50

Comment: @umar khan is that the value of str or the value of minutes. The error message contains the entire string you are trying to parse.

Comment: @PatrickNijhuis it is value of minutes, ya Geraj just told me that i am trying to parse whole String then i fixed it and Now its working. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
String str = String.format("%tM", date );
```

You get the exception because you try to convert a String "Current Date/Time : xx" to a number;

Comment: It works, Thanks Man! ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Indian/Mahe"));
    int currentMinuteOfHour = now.getMinute();
    System.out.println(currentMinuteOfHour);
```

On my computer this just printed

> 53

There’s no need to format the minutes into a string and parse it back.

Also the `Date` class is long outdated (no pun intended). Better to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. And as you can see, it provides for much simpler code.

The current minute depends on time zone. Therefore please provide your intended time zone where I put Indian/Mahe. You may use the current JVM time zone setting: `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. The setting may be changed at any time by other parts of your program or other programs running in the same JVM.

What went wrong in your code? Your `String.format()` call produced a string like `Current Minutes : 43`. This doesn’t conform with the syntax of an integer (`43` alone would). Therefore you got the exception from trying to parse it with `Integer.valueOf(str)`.

**Tutorial link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: I understand, Thanks for providing link. ;)

Answer (score 2):

That is not the correct way to get minutes. If you are using Java 8 or higher version you could do this to get minutes

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime=LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(localDateTime.getMinute());
```

Comment: It is correct that this is the correct solution. It works in Java 6 and 7 too when you add [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your programming project.