# Calendar minute not giving the right minute

Tags: java, datetime, minute, java.util.calendar

The code below shows the text of a parsed `Date` object, and the static field  `Calendar.MINUTE`. Can someone inform why they're different?

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MINUTE) say it's supposed to get the current minute value as an int.

EDIT: image removed, code/result updated.

```
public class Testerson {

  public void print()
  {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
      System.out.println("Date time = " + sdf.format(new Date()));
      System.out.println("Calendar Minute = " + Calendar.MINUTE);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
  {
      Testerson test = new Testerson();
      test.print();
  }
}
```

With an output of;

```
Date time = 08/04/2018 05:49
Calendar Minute = 12
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't add days to Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539049/cant-add-days-to-calendar)

Comment: You may use [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717534/5772882).

Comment: Or as you see it possible duplicate of [Java: getMinutes and getHours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907170/java-getminutes-and-gethours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Calendar.MINUTE` is simply a constant:

```
public final static int MINUTE = 12;
```

If you have an instance of `Calendar` you could get the minute as `calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)`.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't specify minutes you specified seconds in your date format.

your date time is "dd/MM/yyyy hh:ss"
it should be "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

original question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49720176/revisions

[image: original provided code]

Comment: Has nothing to do with the reported problem.

Comment: @lexicore it most certainly does...  if he is trying to figure out why his minutes are different in two methods of accessing time, specifying minutes in his format is a prerequisite.

Comment: this was a last minute mistake before uploading, results were as stated in the question, just displaying incorrectly, updated now.

Comment: i responded to the information you provided.  The first thing that jumped out was a syntax error.

Comment: @me_ The OP prints the `Calendar.MINUTE` constant, so "unexpected" result has nothing to do with the date/time format, it is a much simpler error. Please check other answers which all point it out.

Comment: @lexicore he was also printing out SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:ss");System.out.println("Date time = " + sdf.format(new Date())); and asking why the minutes could be different in each...  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49720176/revisions

Comment: @lexicore even assuming his usage of the calendar method was correct, 59 times every minute the print outs would have been different

Comment: @me_ OK, for that revision you're right the format was not correct. Removed the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar has a static constant field named MINUTE.
You are printing that constant! That value has nothing to do with that date object.

Answer (score 0):

use `Calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)` instead

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.MINUTE` is a constant (`static final`). Since, it’s a constant there is no chance it can give you the current minute, as it should change its value every moment. Thus, your understanding is wrong.

The docs says it’s **a field number to get and set the Minute of hour**. You need to use it to extract the minute value from the calendar instance like below:

```
calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
```